# Dependency Conflict with TOCropViewController in React Native Project

Tags: react-native, dependencies, conflict, react-native-image-crop-picker

I'm currently facing a dependency conflict in my React Native project when trying to use both react-native-image-crop-picker and react-native-image-crop-tools. Each library depends on different versions of TOCropViewController, leading to a conflict that I'm unable to resolve.

Here's the situation:

- react-native-image-crop-picker@0.40.3 does not specify a version for TOCropViewController@2.6.1
- react-native-image-crop-tools@1.6.4 explicitly requires TOCropViewController@2.5.3.
- When I install react-native-image-crop-picker first and then run pod install in the ios directory, it succeeds. However, after adding react-native-image-crop-tools and running pod install again, I encounter the following error:

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "TOCropViewController":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    TOCropViewController (= 2.6.1)

  In Podfile:
    RNImageCropPicker (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-picker`) was resolved to 0.40.3, which depends on
      TOCropViewController

    react-native-image-crop-tools (from `../node_modules/react-native-image-crop-tools`) was resolved to 1.6.4, which depends on
      TOCropViewController (= 2.5.3)
```

I understand this is a basic dependency conflict so i added pod 'TOCropViewController', '2.5.3' in Podfile. But it is not still working.
How to solve this?
Any advice is welcome. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is necessary to use those two packages, you can try manually to adjust the version **TOCropViewController** inside **react-native-image-crop-picker**, until it is working as expected or directly disable it, if it possible. Then using https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package you can apply your changes to the **patch** every time you install/update your node modules. Keep in mind this is a solution where the two packages are a must.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I've implemented the updates using patch-package to ensure these modifications are reflected each time the node modules are installed or updated.

I'm sincerely thankful for your guidance and wish you a wonderful day

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the react-native-image-crop-picker utilizes version 2.6.1 of TOCropViewController, which introduces a property not present in version 2.5.3. Since react-native-image-crop-tools was using the latter version, this incompatibility prompted me to update the TOCropViewController version in the react-native-image-crop-tools.

Specifically, I changed the dependency version in the podspec located at

`node_modules/react-native-image-crop-tools/react-native-image-crop-tools/podspec` from:

s.dependency 'TOCropViewController', '2.5.3'
=> s.dependency 'TOCropViewController', '2.6.1'